# Excel Solver and VBA: Floating point/decimal numbers in constraints get incorrectly converted to integers?

Tags: excel, vba, floating-point, solver

I'm running VBA scripts under both Excel 2007 and 2010 which involve a lot of optimization using the built-in Solver of Excel.

What is the correct way to specify decimal constraints like X>=0.0001 where X would be the decision variable of the problem.

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=cells(5,5), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.0001"
```

Or do I have to remove the quotes " " ?
And does the VBA interface of Solver allow for decimal (non-integer) constraints anyway?

I'm asking, because sometimes I get the (unconfirmed) feeling that a constraint of >=0.0001 is incorrectly interpreted as >=1, which of course renders wrong results.

It would be great if somebody could clarify these issues for me.

Steve

Comment: I never used the Solver as is, but could not multiplying everything with 10000 help, as this makes your float essantially to an integer? Sure in the end you need to divide by 10000 again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We've found that `FormulaText` can really effect the final solution.  We've always just used straight numbers there, no quotes:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=cells(5,5), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=0.0001
```